# spark skipping the json attributes with nulls

Tags: json, apache-spark

All,

I am trying to read the JSON file, and there are some attributes with null values; those are getting dropped when I show() the data frame.

current spark version:2.4

json :

```
{ "name":"Bob", "location":"NYC", "empl":null}

df.show()
name | location
------------------
Bob  |NYC
======================
```

Can you please help, how to display the "empl" in the output?

thanks

Comment: Can you show us how you import the json file?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df = (spark
        .read
        .option('dropFieldIfAllNull', False)
        .json('your file path')      
)
```